# Keep white space with htmlentities

Tags: php, file-get-contents, html-entities, nl2br

Currently, this is my code

```
$str = file_get_contents($sFile);
echo nl2br(htmlentities($str));
```

How can I keep the whitespace (tab and multiple spaces) in the files when i output them?

Example Input:

```
if(a==b){
  code   
    more code 
}
```

Should ouput exactly that (with htmlentities applied), but currently outputs

```
if(a==b){
code
more code
}
```

How can I keep whitespace?

Comment: The browser will automatically collapse/convert the whitespace characters into a single space. You can wrap the text in a <pre></pre> element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the output in `<pre>...</pre>` tags:

```
<pre>
if(a==b){
  code   
    more code 
}
</pre>
```

Browsers ignore superfluous whitespace, so you have to tell it not to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html entity for space to keep the space:

`echo str_replace([' ', "\t"], ['&nbsp;', '&nbsp;&nbsp;'], nl2br(htmlentities($str)));`